# htaccess RewriteRule redirecting for URL's without trailing slashes

Tags: .htaccess

I have this snippet in my `.htaccess` file to defend against anyone trying to get into the app directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And although it works when I go to `http://domain/app/`, if I make a request to `http://domain/app`, it redirects to `http://domain/app/?r=app`.

Does anyone know what needs to be changed to stop such redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `DirectorySlash` directive that can be use globally or per directory.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: Wow ... Six month too late. Did not see that ... sorry.

Comment: thats ok, thanks for noticing and answering :) I had abandoned this and chosen another path, but now I might return

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
[L]
```

instead of

```
[L,QSA]
```